# convert character time period (in a weird format) to date and time in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector of the form "`01jan1990 1 a.m. to 2 p.m.`" etc. and would like to convert this into separate Date and Times, where the times are both the beginning and end of the range. So far, I have used `strsplit` to separate it at "to" and then tried to use parse_date_time for the second half, but I end up with something like this `0000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC`. I don't even know how to convert the first half.

The functions in R don't seem to support such a format. I am very confused. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remove all dots from the input giving `s1` and then remove the `1 am to` from that giving s2.  We can now convert those two to POSIXct giving t1 and t2 and from those extract the dates and the times.  We have shown this for the input in the question but it would continue to work if s were a character vector of such inputs.  No packages are used.

```
s <- "01jan1990 1 a.m. to 2 p.m"

s1 <- gsub("\\.", "", s)
s2 <- sub("\\d+ \\S+ to ", "", s1)

fmt <- "%d%b%Y %I %p"
t1 <- as.POSIXct(s1, format = fmt)
t2 <- as.POSIXct(s2, format = fmt)

as.Date(t1); as.Date(t2)
## [1] "1990-01-01"
## [1] "1990-01-01"

sub(".* ", "", format(t1)); sub(".* ", "", format(t2))
## [1] "01:00:00" 
## [1] "14:00:00"
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. My only issue is that the final line (sub(".* ", "", format(t1)); sub(".* ", "", format(t2)) sets the times to character format. I want them all to be date-time objects so I can perform mathematical operations on them. Is there a function I could use that is analogous to the as.Date function but for times?

Comment: t1 and t2 are date time objects.  A POSIXct object always has both date and times, not just times; however, times class in chron is available and that is pure times:  `library(chron) ; times(sub(".* ", "", format(t1))); times(sub(".* ", "", format(t2)))`  You could also decide to just store t1 and t2 and forget about storing the date and time separately.  You can always extract them if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract data into three columns

```
x <- c("01jan1990 1 a.m. to 2 p.m.", "10jan1990 9 a.m. to 2 p.m.")

data <- strcapture('(\\w+) (\\d+ .\\..)\\. to (\\d+ .\\..)', x,
           proto = list(date = character(), start = character(), end = character()))

data
#       date start   end
#1 01jan1990 1 a.m 2 p.m
#2 10jan1990 9 a.m 2 p.m
```

Paste the date values to start and end and convert to `POSIXct` format.

```
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], function(x) as.POSIXct(paste(data$date, 
            sub('.', '', x, fixed = TRUE)), format = '%d%b%Y %I %p', tz = 'UTC'))
data

#       date               start                 end
#1 01jan1990 1990-01-01 01:00:00 1990-01-01 14:00:00
#2 10jan1990 1990-01-10 09:00:00 1990-01-10 14:00:00
```